# Is it possible to query the chattergoup where the current user is in in one query

Tags: apex, soql, chatter-groups, inner-join, outer-join

I am trying to get the group where the current user is in. In this case the user can only be member of one group.

I tried the following but the I would have to loop trough the CollaborationGroup

```
    User currentUser = [SELECT Id, Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
            List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroups = [SELECT Id,Name, (SELECT id,MemberId FROM GroupMembers WHERE MemberId = :currentUser.id LIMIT 1) From CollaborationGroup]

;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that your `SELECT` subquery against `GroupMembers` does not perform any filtering on the `CollaborationGroup` list that's returned - it only filters the member data you get back as part of the `CollaborationGroup` sObjects.

So when you do this:

```
chatterGroups = [SELECT Id, Name, 
                        (SELECT id, MemberId 
                         FROM GroupMembers 
                         WHERE MemberId = :currentUser.id LIMIT 1) 
                 From CollaborationGroup];
```

what you get back is every single `CollaborationGroup` in your org, along with any `GroupMember` records where the `MemberId` is the current user.

Instead, you can use a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin):

```
chatterGroups = [SELECT Id, Name 
                 FROM CollaborationGroup
                 WHERE Id IN (SELECT CollaborationGroupId 
                              FROM CollaborationGroupMember 
                              WHERE MemberId = :UserInfo.getUserId())];
```

That will in fact filter the returned group list to *only* those groups of which the current user is a member.

This pattern is widely applicable to situations where you need to filter a parent object based on the presence or absence of a child object matching some criteria or other.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In this case where do you refer to in the documentation to know that CollaborationGroupMember is a child of CollaborationGroup?

Comment: I generally just look at the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupmember.htm#!) for the object I want.

Comment: Ah ok I expected something as the Datamodel Chatter Objects and maybe an easier way in the Org itself. But thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. You want the [Chatter ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm).